# How can the time difference between two consecutive rows from different columns be calculated?

Tags: r, time

## Data example

```
n1 <- as.POSIXct(c('2006-12-10 13:01:22', '2006-12-11 12:13:11', 
                   '2006-12-12 13:12:11', '2006-12-13 11:01:22', 
                   '2006-12-14 15:13:11', '2006-12-15 13:12:11',
                   '2006-12-16 16:13:12', '2006-12-17 14:12:12'))

n2 <- as.POSIXct(c('2006-12-10 16:01:22', '2006-12-11 13:13:11', 
                   '2006-12-12 15:12:11', '2006-12-13 14:01:22', 
                   '2006-12-14 17:13:11', '2006-12-15 16:12:11',
                   NA, '2006-12-17 16:12:12'))

date <- as.data.frame(n1)
date$n2 <- n2
```

How can I get the time difference between date$n2[1] and date$n1[2], followed by date$n2[2] and date$n1[3], until the end of the vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `difftime` `across` the columns between the current row of 'n1' and `lag` of 'n2'

```
library(dplyr)
date %>%
    mutate(diff = difftime(n1, lag(n2), unit = 'min'))
```